# Issue importing state/province from non-US countries

Tags: import

I'm importing contacts from a legacy system and am running into a wall importing addresses from non-US countries. For instance, for Canada, I'm trying to import a Canadian province. I've tried both the full name and the two-character abbreviation (e.g. "Saskatchewan" or "SK") and neither works. I have confirmed that the provinces are correctly included in the civicrm_state_province database table. The import error states:

```
Invalid value for field(s) : State
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. If you can provide steps to reproduce, ideally with a small sample file, please open an issue on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core

Answer (score 4):

You MUST un-set the “Default Country” on the Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Locations page before importing non-US addresses. Unsetting this value (which I had set to United States) allow the import to proceed without getting the error. This seems like a bug in the import module (?).